# Not sure how to delete rows in this format of mysql

Tags: mysql

Need some mysql help- trying to delete from a database where posts have been marked deleted.

UPDATE `nobanchancom`.`aasposts` DELETE `aasposts` WHERE `aasposts`.`IS_DELETED` =1

I need it to delete the whole row in which IS_DELETED = 1

Comment: You have the answer in your own question: `DELETE from aasposts WHERE IS_DELETED =1`

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
DELETE FROM nobanchancom.aasposts WHERE is_deleted = 1;
```